# Get highest value given a key

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have performed the following query:

```
db.Indiv2.aggregate(
    {$unwind: '$conso'},
    {$group: {_id: {conso:'$conso.nom_commercial', region:"$region"}, sum: {$sum: 1}}},
    {$sort : {sum : -1}}
);
```

which returns the following:

```
    {
        "_id" : {
            "conso" : "x",
            "region" : 1
        },
        "sum" : 73226.0
    },
    {
        "_id" : {
            "conso" : "x",
            "region" : 8
        },
        "sum" : 25683.0
    },
    {
        "_id" : {
            "conso" : "grandlait demi �cr�m� uht",
            "region" : 1
        },
        "sum" : 251.0
    }
```

There are 21 different regions and I am trying to get the most consumed item by region. How could I use "sum" to return the highest value given each region?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be enough for you to add the following two stages to the end of your aggregation pipeline:

```
$group: {
    _id: "$_id.region",
    "conso": {
        $first: "$_id.conso"
    },
    "sum": {
        $first: "$sum"
    }
}
```